# Youtube data API in javascript to notify new videos

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a Chrome / Mozilla extension and I wanted to add a new feature. It has to check periodically if a new video is published on a channel, and if yes, it notifies it. I developed it with Youtube data API, but due to the amount people who are using my extension, quotas are reached really fast and 100 Api keys would not even be enough. Could anyone tell me if I can use something else and what/how? There is only content scripts in my extensions.

Edit : To use Youtube data api, I need to put a key with each request. Each  key has a daily limit. Each extension (user) directly ask youtube with this API and the same keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can make check on server side. Periodically check and save results.

Extensions will request server and get result.

---

One request from the server, instead of a hundred requests from every extension.

Comment: You want me to put a server between extensions (users) and youtube? It could work, but now I have to find how to do it. thank you

Comment: @Nucktrooper, yes. For example you have 100 users. 100 users = 100 installed extension. They send requests to YouTube (100 requests).
In my version only server sends requests to YouTube (1 request). Extension communicate only with your server. Thus, you will not exceed the quota on requests.

Comment: Ok. Actually, it's about 34k users and I don't earn anything with my extensions. So I need to find a server host who can handle it for free, and then, how to develop it. ^^